# How to install FreeBSD in minimum size?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, squid

I want to install FreeBSD to run a squid cache server on it. I want to know how can I can make this installation as small as possible?

I installed the boot-only ISO file on virtual box, but it took around 600 megabytes. By the way it is an old machine so I want it work in this minimum size.

Is there any script to download just the needed files and which file system is the best for squid cache holding partition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, even with minimal installation, the current FreeBSD requires a minimum of 600 MB, especially if you go for a amd64 release.

There is still some options left:

1. **Installing a *NanoBSD***

   This is a way of generating a bare-minimal system image from a living one.

   You will choose exactly what to keep, but this is no ordinary click-type installation. Here is the [procedure to build a *NanoBSD*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/nanobsd/index.html) (this is still up-to-date).
2. **Using a specialized system (*pfSense*, ...)**

   There are some specialized FreeBSD based systems which are more or less able to run a `squid` for caching (in fact they are also based on a NanoBSD). Here are some examples:

   - [pfSense](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Main_Page)
   - [m0n0Wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/facts.php) (last update is 2014, so maybe considering [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/about/about-opnsense/) instead)
3. **Using an "old" 7.x or 8.x (i386) release**

   As a last option, installing an "old" 7.3 (i386) with everything to minimal took 270 MB.

   If you don't care about having a 64 bits system and having regular security updates, this old system might be enough for your needs.